# Yii validation rules for min value or empty

Tags: yii

I want to add a rule where user can post empty value, or integer value shoud be in range min-max.
Is this possible without custom rules?

So, if min is 5 and max is 10, user could post values: empty, 5,6,7,8,9 or 10.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [numerical](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh16) validator by setting its `min` to `5`, `max` to `10`, `allowEmpty` and `integerOnly` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('test', 'safe'),
            array('test', 'length', 'min' => 5, 'max'=>10, 
            'tooShort'=>Yii::t("translation", "{attribute} to short."),
            'tooLong'=>Yii::t("translation", "{attribute} to long.")),

            array('test', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[0-9]+$/'), 
        );
    }
```